# why do we take this partition?

Tags: analysis

I am looking at the following exercise:

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with:

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 &,x=0 \\ 
0 &,0<x \leq 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Show with the definition that $f$ is integrable and calculate the integral.

I saw at the solution that they take the partition: $P_{\epsilon}=\{ 0< \epsilon<1\}$..

But why to we take this partition??

Comment: How would you have solved the exercise?

Comment: What does this notation mean $\{0<\epsilon<1\}$?

Comment: @mathse It means $\{0,\epsilon,1\}$ where $\epsilon\in(0,1)$.

Comment: So the partition of the unit interval is $[0,\epsilon)$, $[\epsilon,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that for (small enough) $\varepsilon > 0$ we pick the partition $0 < \varepsilon < 2 \varepsilon < 3 \varepsilon < ... < 1$, which has norm $\delta = \varepsilon$.
Perhaps that partition is intended?

Comment: I don't think so.. We calculate,for example, $U(f,P_{\epsilon})$ like that: $U(f,P_{\epsilon})=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (t_{k+1}-t_{k}) sup f([t_k,t_{k+1}])=(\epsilon-0) supf([0, \epsilon])+ (1-\epsilon) supf([\epsilon,1])=\epsilon \cdot 1+(1-\epsilon) \cdot 0=\epsilon$.

Comment: It seems to me that $t_k=k\epsilon$ identifies the partition $0 <\epsilon <2\epsilon <... < 1$ as it should for a Riemann integral. Then, as a second step, this is simplified to $0 < \epsilon < 1$, which is possible since the summation on (\epsilon, 1) is 0.

Comment: I understand..Thank you very much!!!! $\smile$